# Installing PHP Tidy on MAMP

Tags: php, mamp, tidy

MAMP and MAMP PRO does not come with php [Tidy](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.tidy.php). This is a commonly used to clean up html.

Please post instructions for installing Tidy under MAMP. The current version of MAMP as of this post is 2.2. If there are specific instructions for different versions please post these as well.

Answer (score 3):

Instructions for MAMP 2.2 with PHP 5.3.27

Most of this was lifted from: http://lucor.github.io/post/how-enable-the-php-tidy-extension-for-mamp/

NOTE: I already have OSX Dev tools installed (brew / XCode) so these *may* be required but they are not listed as I did not have a clean install.

**Download** PHP 5.3.27 http://www.php.net/get/php-5.3.27.tar.bz2/from/a/mirror
If you want to use a different PHP version find that on http://www.php.net/releases/

**Uncompress**

```
tar xvjf php-5.3.27.tar.bz2
cd php-5.3.27
```

**Setup compile flags** Instruct the system to build universal binaries, that will work on both 32 and 64 bit systems by entering the following commands in the terminal console.

```
MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.9 #Replace with your version.
CFLAGS="-arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -Os -pipe -no-cpp-precomp"
CCFLAGS="-arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -Os -pipe"CXXFLAGS="-arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -Os -pipe"
LDFLAGS="-arch i386 -arch x86_64 -bind_at_load"
export CFLAGS CXXFLAGS LDFLAGS CCFLAGS MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET
```

**Configure and Compile PHP**
This is the part that will build the lib. You will be throwing away everything except the tidy.so extension

```
LIBS=-lresolv ./configure --with-tidy=shared && make
```

**Copy extension** to MAMP php lib folder.

```
cp modules/tidy.so /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.27/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/
```

**Configure PHP.ini** to load extension. This can be done in the MAMP GUI as well. Since MAMP Pro recreates the php.ini upon server restart, you have to edit the template file.

```
echo "extension=tidy.so" >> /Library/Application\ Support/appsolute/MAMP\ PRO/conf/php.ini
```

Comment: All this, when **W**AMP lets you `Options > PHP > Extensions > Enable Tidy`

Comment: v10.15.6 should remove the -arch i386 from the flags as it is not longer supported

Answer (score 0):

On 2023, MAMP 6.8 has the tidy.so in its php directories

you can append

`extension={your MAMP application path}/bin/php/php{your_PHP_version}/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-{something}/tidy.so`

in your php.ini file

I've tried with

```
[tidy]
extension="/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.4.33/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/tidy.so"
tidy.clean_output=0
```

and I can see the tidy extension enabled when running phpinfo();